# RadioGroup onCheckChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) not working correctly with dynamic forms

Tags: android, radio-group

Dynamic forms on Android can be very confusing, and I have run into this specific situation where I am creating a list of options via a `RadioGroup` with `AppCompatRadioButton`s where the checkedId is not contextual with the Dynamic `RadioGroup`:

```
String [] options = new String[] {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"};

 private void buildDynamicRadioGroup(){
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MyActivity.class);
    final RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(MyActivity.class);
    for(String option: options){
       final AppCompatRadioButton radioButton = new AppCompatRadioButton(MyActivity.class);
       radioButton.setText(option);
       radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             Log.d("Checked Group Count", group.getChildCount()); // this is always 4
             Log.d("Option Id", checkedId); // this prints correctly the first time              
        }
    });
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);
 }
```

This looks okay for the first call to `buildDynamicRadioGroup()`, however every addition call to the method (i.e. n > 1) the `checkedId` is reflective of the total count of `AppCompatRadioButton` that have been built by calling this method, not the actual `checkedId` of the `RadioGroup` in question...

For example: the second call to the method prints 4, and 6 if the 2 item is selected in the 2 group of `RadioButton`s since there are 6 `AppCompatRadioButton`s

Anyone know how to handle this so I only get the `checkedId` in context with the `RadioGroup` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just today I had the same problem and found your question when searching for a solution. The only difference is that I am loading the `RadioButtons` from XML resources.

For me the problem was, that all radio buttons had the same ID. The `RadioGroup` is working with these IDs when toggling the states for the radio buttons.

I could solve my problem by changing the ID of the radio buttons before adding them to the `RadioGroup`. Therefore I am just adding a random positive ID:

```
private View createViewForButton(                                            
        final Context context,                                               
        final Option radioButton) {                                          

    final View view =                                                        
        getLayoutInflater(context).inflate(R.layout.form_radiobutton, null); 

    final RadioButton label = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.label_view);    
    label.setText(radioButton.getValue());                                   

    makeButtonWorkingInRadioGroup(view);                                     

    return view;                                                             
}                                                                            

private void makeButtonWorkingInRadioGroup(final View view) {                
    // The radio group requires all RadioButtons to have different IDs to    
    // work correctly. This wouldn't work else as we are loading all         
    // RadioButtons from the same XML file having the same ID definition.    
    view.setId(View.generateViewId());                                                  
}
```

Make sure that the IDs you set are positive. With negative IDs its also not working.

Comment: Wow that was my second guess I forgot to post that. But when we do this, we have a tiny chance we will overlap. I do this: `int id = 12345; for (String option : options) { ... radioButton.setText(option); radio.setId(id + 1); id += 1; ...`

Comment: In general: There are 2^31 possible values, that can be generated. When you have four radio buttons (as an example), that probability of a collision is about 6 * 2^-31 which is less than 8 * 2^-31 = 2^-29.
Because your algorithm is running on real hardware you have to compare this with the probability of errors generated there (flipping bits and the like). This probability is just so much higher, that you don't have to care about a collision generated this way. I know it's hard to get used to this calculations when you start randomized algorithms, but it's just reality.

Comment: In the special case: I stopped using Random for this as well. View has a special static method to generate viewIds which can be used very nicely here: View.generateViewId().

Comment: I learn something new every day. I always used my method but this is much easier.